# Efficient way to find max and min latitude and longitude using solr spatial search

Tags: solr, spatial

Scenario :
I need to find the bounding co-ordinates for all the objects, such that they lie within a specific geographic co-ordinate boundary. Each object has its own location. And I'm using datastax with solr.

To solve this I'm indexing latitude and longitude column separately, and performing sorted pagination search to get the top and last object with has min and max latitude value and same for longitude. Now using (min_lon, min_lat) and (max_lon, max_lat) I get the bottom left and top right corner co-ordinate for the bounding box.

Is there any other way to perform this task ? I'm also thinking of performance issue over large data set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Stats component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent) of Solr to achieve this. Presumably this should work as of Solr 1.4, though I have only tested it on Solr 4.6.

Given a *latitude* and *longitude* field (you don't need to store the values, you just need to index the fields) you can add the following to your query:

`stats=true&stats.field=latitude&stats.field=longitude`

This will return an additional *stats* component in your results, which will include the min and max values for those field over the query you just run. For instance, using the json output format, you will get something like this as part of your result:

```js
"stats": {
  "stats_fields": {
    "latitude": {
      "min": -77.0833,
      "max": 80.02,
      "count": 946,
      "missing": 9054,
      "sum": 7071.808743139995,
      "sumOfSquares": 826744.9247004522,
      "mean": 7.475484929323462,
      "stddev": 28.61678430457283,
      "facets": {}
    },
    "longitude": {
      "min": -170.0172222,
      "max": 179.3667,
      "count": 946,
      "missing": 9054,
      "sum": 19608.08470332999,
      "sumOfSquares": 4377841.608102106,
      "mean": 20.727362265676522,
      "stddev": 64.82714283188912,
      "facets": {}
    }
  }
}
```